# CheckedListbox weird behavior in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have CheckedListbox bound to List. However I notice, the weird behavior of this control. I have to first select an item and then check that item. Why can't I directly select an item in the list? If this control behaves this way by design then, is there any other control which can give me the behavior that I am looking for?

I don't want to select an item just to be able to check it.

Comment: if you have many items in listbox how does it know which one to be selected?

Comment: @coder: If I check the checkbox, why can't it know "that" is the item that I want to be selected? Is that too hard?

Comment: @coder: The behavior that I want to accomplished can be done I guess by dynamically adding checkboxes to some panel. That way I don't have to select any item just to be able to check that item.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you can use checked changed event for this and in that mention the item to be selected.

Comment: @coder: No you did not understand what I mean to say. See the answers by Steve or Ove. They were exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `CheckOnClick` property of the CheckedListBox to make it check the item when it's clicked. If you set it to `True`, you don't have to click twice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called CheckOnClick-

Set it to true.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkonclick.aspx)
CheckOnClick indicates whether the check box should be toggled whenever an item is selected. The default behavior is to change the selection on the first click, and then have the user click again to apply the check mark. In some instances, however, you might prefer have the item checked as soon as it is clicked.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Coder's comment frightened me.